# How do I get a div's outer height?

Tags: jquery, html

I've encountered this problem before and have not really found a solution. I have this html (simplified):

```
<div class="outer">
    <header>my header section</header>
    <div id="body">
        <h1>Page H1</h1>
        <p class="content"></p>
    </div>
    <footer>footer section</footer>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to get the actual height of #body (using jQuery) like this:

```
var b = $('#body').outerHeight(true);
```

But that is not returning what I think is the correct height. The height I expect is the height that FireFox also reports in the "Box Model" (in Developer Tools). But jQuery is returning a different value, which appears to exclude the top margin of the h1 tag.

I also tried to use innerHeight of #body but it returns the same value. Anyone has an idea of how to do it, hopefully without having to iterate through the child elements?

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4g78/) for your reference.

Comment: the problem is that there is a margin between #body and header [http://jsfiddle.net/e4g78/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/e4g78/2/)

Comment: I don't have enough time to investigate this properly as an answer, but it might be also worth having a look at `getBoundingClientRect().height`? http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/06/inside-the-box-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: if you want the parent's bounding box to include a child's margin, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: When are you trying that? just as it is? on `$(function)` ? on `$(document).ready()` or in `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: @AbrahamUribe, I do not want to (nor think I should) remove the margin on h1 to solve the problem.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet, the fiddle answers your question. (I do it when the document is ready.)

Comment: You can float your elements, give them display inline block, or try other solutions to remedy the collapsed margins described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stuart's answer explains the height 'anomaly', if I can call it that. Thanks to @Stuart. His answer led me to look for a solution for that scenario.

Here's an [SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909956/how-to-calculate-an-elements-height-considering-collapsed-margins) which mentions a hack, which appears to work on IE8, Chrome and FF. And it addresses my need. Here's [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4g78/4/) for anyone interested. Basically, I had to change the way I calculate the height as follows (and remove the wrapping afterwards):

```
   var b = $('div#body').wrap('<div style="border:1px solid transparent;"></div>' ).parent().height();
   $('div#body').unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks @frank, I think the same could be achieved by simply applying a transparent border to the element in your CSS, or by using floats, or taking any of the routes described in the linked W3C spec on canceling collapsed margins. Interesting question here though, and I learned some stuff in the process.

Comment: Unless you *actually want the collapsed margins! In which case your solution solves the problem, gets the proper height, and then reapplies the collapsing :)

Comment: Really interesting scenario.

Comment: Hi @Stuart, I really cannot change the content nor the content's styling so I'm hesitant to change margins or introduce floats. The hack is less intrusive. Yes, it is really interesting and without you telling me about collapsed margin, I would be pulling my hair by now :)))

Answer (score 4):

This may be due to a box model feature known as 'collapsing margins'. Individually, these elements should return their proper calculated heights, but when margins collapse as stacked, the result may account for your discrepancy.

Here's an excellent article describing the scenario: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

> In simple terms, this definition indicates that when the vertical
>   margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element
>   with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the
>   element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero.
>
> This behavior is best demonstrated with a short example. Consider the
>   following code:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background: #cff;
}
div {
  margin: 40px 0 25px 0;
  background: #cfc;
}
p {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  background: #cf9;
}

<h1>Heading Content</h1>
<div>
  <p>Paragraph content</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Further info can be found at the W3C Box Model spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

> When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the
>   maximum of the collapsing margins' widths. In the case of negative
>   margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the negative adjoining
>   margins is deducted from the maximum of the positive adjoining
>   margins. If there are no positive margins, the maximum of the absolute
>   values of the adjoining margins is deducted from zero.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart. I get what you and the article are saying, but it does not quite explain why jQuery would calculate the height of the container without considering the margin (collapsed or not) of the child elements.

Comment: The margins are not factored into the document height when calculated as a whole, because they are then collapsed. If you remedy the collapsed margins does that solve the discrepancy? I'm very curious. Try floating the elements to test.

Comment: I think your answer explains the why. So thanks for that. And it lead me to find this hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909956/how-to-calculate-an-elements-height-considering-collapsed-margins. This appears to work based on this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4g78/3/

Comment: Thanks @frank, I think the same could be achieved by simply applying a transparent border to the element in your CSS, or by using floats, or taking any of the routes described in the linked W3C spec on canceling collapsed margins. Interesting question here though, and I learned some stuff in the process.